# Don't Know How to Add Existing Image Upload Capabilities to a New Form

Tags: php, html, forms, function, variables

I'm a fairly novice webmaster whom is working hard to setup a classifieds for my users. (I'm basically rebuilding a poorly written classifieds)

I had bought a cheap classifieds program so I'd have something to learn PHP off of and I've come a long ways but I'm still a long ways off from understanding how to tie everything together with an existing image upload functionality and if anyone wouldn't mind helping me, I'd be most appreciative.

Allow me to explain;

In this classifieds earliest days, a visitor had to add their listing (which was a bitch) THEN the visitor had to go looking for where they could upload their images. Needless to say, that wasn't cutting it.

Fast Fwd to Present; Now I have a form on a page with several text inputs (ie; text, select, textarea and a checkbox) as well as on this form I have 4 image upload buttons as can be seen below.

```
<form id="generalform" class="container" method="POST"  action="addlistingprocess.php" autocomplete="on" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        <div class='field'>
        <label for='TypeID'>I'm Selling A:</label>
        <select name='TypeID'>
        <option value='42'>Motorcycle</option>
        <option value='43'>New or Used Part</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Year">* Year:</label>
        <input type="number" class="input" name="Year" maxlength="5" min="1963" max="2013" value="2013">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="fatherID">* Make:</label>
        <select name='fatherID'>
        <option>-- Select Manufacturer --</option>
        <option value='10'>Honda</option>
        <option value='35'>Husqvarna</option>
        <option value='36'>Kawasaki</option>
        <option value='37'>KTM</option>
        <option value='38'>Suzuki</option>
        <option value='39'>Yamaha</option>
        <option value='40'>Other</option>
        <option value='46'>It's Vintage or Evo</option>
        </select>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Model">* Model:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="Model" maxlength="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Model'])) echo $_POST['Model']; ?>" placeholder="(i.e. CRF450F, KX 450F...)">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Description">* Details About It:</label><br>
        <textarea name="Description" rows="10" cols="60"><?php if(isset($_POST['Description'])) echo $_POST['Description']; ?></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Vin">VIN:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" name="VIN" maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['VIN'])) echo $_POST['VIN']; ?>" placeholder="Optional">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Price">* Asking Price ($):</label>
        <input type="number" class="input" name="Price" maxlength="10" min="0" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Price'])) echo $_POST['Price']; ?>">
        </div>
        <!--
        <h4>Upload Up To 4 Images</h4>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Image">Image 1</label>
        <input type="file" class="fileuploadinput" name="Image1">
        <label for="Image">Image 2</label>
        <input type="file" class="fileuploadinput" name="Image2">
        <label for="Image">Image 3</label>
        <input type="file" class="fileuploadinput" name="Image3">
        <label for="Image">Image 4</label>
        <input type="file" class="fileuploadinput" name="Image4">
        </div>
                -->
        <br>
        <hr style="width:60%">
        <br>

        <h3>Where It's Located:</h3>
        <div class="field">
        <label for="Address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="Address" name="Address" maxlength="40" placeholder="Optional" />
        <p class="hint">40 Characters Maximum</p>   
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="City">* City:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="City" name="City" maxlength="20" />
        <p class="hint">20 Characters Maximum</p>   
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="State">* State / Province:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="State" name="State" maxlength="20" />
        <p class="hint">20 Characters Maximum</p>   
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="ZIP">* ZIP:</label>
        <input type="text" class="input" id="ZIP" name="ZIP" maxlength="20" />
        <p class="hint">20 Characters Maximum</p>   
        </div>

        <div class="field">
        <label for="Country">* Country:</label>
        <select name="Country">
<option selected="selected" value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
</select>
</div>      
        <input type="checkbox" name="Inform" value="1" checked/> Keep Me Dialed In With Site Updates & Specials<br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit My Ad"/>
        </form>
```

Now here's the kicker, (and sorry for creating such a long post)

This classifieds already has an existing image upload functionality which I'd like to retain as it handles resizing and displaying the images such as can  be seen here: 
http://classifieds.your-adrenaline-fix.com/detail.php?fatherID=10&TypeID=42&ListingID=7

I want to tie this functionality to the form above, however, this program requires a lot of paramaters of which I have tried for weeks to understand, yet still don't. (However I have cleaned the sh^$ out of the code in an effort  to understand it)

I'm going to close this thread with all applicable files as code and if anyone could help me with this I'd be most grateful and I thank you all in advance.

This is images.php. (This is where a visitor had to navigate to AFTER creating their ad but it's also where a visitor can add or delete photos associated with their listing so I need to keep this)

```
<?php
    include('header.php');  

    if(!$superUser){
        if(!$login){            
            echo "<h2>Please Login to Manage Photos</h2>";
            include('z-login-form.php');
            include('no-ad-footer.php');
            die();
            }
        }

    if($_POST['POrder'] != "") {    
        if (($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpeg') && ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/jpg') && ($_FILES['file']['type'] != 'image/pjpeg')) {
            echo "<script>alert('Images Must be in jpg format and under 2 Mb');\n";
            echo sprintf("window.location='images.php?TypeID=%s&ListingID=%s'", $_POST['TypeID'], $_POST['ListingID']);
            echo "</script>";
            include('no-ad-footer.php');
            die();
        }

        chdir('admin/photos'); 
        require_once('upload.php');
        chdir('../../');

    if ($up->ValidateUpload()) { 
            $node = new sqlNode();
            $node->table = "photos";
            $node->push("int","POrder",$_POST['POrder']);
            $node->push("text","Location",$new_name);
            $node->push("int","TypeID",$_POST['TypeID']);
            $node->push("int","ListingID",$_POST['ListingID']);

            if(($result = $mysql->insert($node)) === false)
                die('Unable to push POrder, Location, TypeID and ListingID into table photos line 38');         
        } else {
            echo "<font color='red'>Unable to upload image</font>";
            }
    }   

    if(($_REQUEST['TypeID'] != "") && ($_REQUEST['ListingID'] != "")) {     
        if(!$superUser){
            echo "<a href='memberindex.php'>Return to My Listings</a>";
        }       

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `types` WHERE ID = %s", intval($_REQUEST['TypeID']));
        $result = $mysql->exSql($sql) or die('Unable to Retrieve Type ID from table types');
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
            die('Less Than One Result Returned from table types. Line51 images.php');
        }

        if(!$superUser){
            $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `tt_%s` WHERE MemberID = %s AND ID = %s", abs(intval($_REQUEST['TypeID'])), intval($_SESSION['memberID']), intval($_REQUEST['ListingID']));
            $result = $mysql->exSql($sql) or die('Unable to select data from table tt__');
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)<1){
                die("<script>window.location='logout.php';</script>");
            }
        }

        $node = new sqlNode();
        $node->table = "photos";
        $node->select = "*";
        $node->where = "WHERE TypeID = ".intval($_REQUEST['TypeID'])." AND ListingID = ".intval($_REQUEST['ListingID']);
        $node->orderby = "ORDER BY `POrder` ASC";

        if(($result = $mysql->select($node)) === false )
            die('Unable to Retrieve data from table photos');

        $num_of_photos = mysql_num_rows($result);

        echo "<h2>Upload or Delete Photos</h2>";

        $showform = true;

        if($showform) {     
            echo "<form action='images.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='TypeID' value='".$_REQUEST['TypeID']."'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='ListingID' value='".$_REQUEST['ListingID']."'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='Upload' value='true'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='POrder' value='".($num_of_photos+1)."'>";

            echo "<table border=0>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>Image 1</td><td><input type='file' name='file' accept='image/*' id='file'></td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type='submit' value='Upload File(s)'></td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
            echo "</form>";
        } else {
            echo "<font color='red'>Max Number of Photos Reached</font>";
        }

        if($num_of_photos >=1) {
        //Print photo table
        echo "<br>";
        echo "<center><strong>$num_of_photos Photo(s) Associated With This Listing</strong></center>";      
        echo "<table class='subHeader' align='center'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>Photo</td><td>Order&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>Action</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //For each photo
        while($photo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td valign=top align=center>";
            echo "<a target='_blank' href='admin/photos/uploads/".$photo['Location']."' title='Click To View Full Size Photo'><img src='admin/photos/uploads/small_thumbs/tn_".$photo['Location']."' border=0></a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$photo['POrder']."</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a href='deleteimage.php?TypeID=".$photo['TypeID']."&ListingID=".$photo['ListingID']."&PhotoID=".$photo['ID']."'>Delete</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    }
    }
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";  


    include('no-ad-footer.php');

?>
```

**This is upload.php**

```
<?php
require_once("UploadFile.class.php");   
$up = new UploadImage($file, 2097152, 3000, 3000,'file',"uploads", $rename_file=true);

if(true) {                                         
    $new_name = $up->CopyFile();
    $imagefolder='.';
    $thumbsfolder='.';
    echo "Creating thumbnail image...<br>";

    function createthumb($name,$filename,$new_w,$new_h) {
        $system=explode(".",$name);
        if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg/",$system[1])){$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($name);}
        if (preg_match("/png/",$system[1])){$src_img=imagecreatefrompng($name);}
        $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
        $old_y=imageSY($src_img);
        if ($old_x > $old_y) {
            $thumb_w=$new_w;
            $thumb_h=$old_y*($new_h/$old_x);
        }
        if ($old_x < $old_y) {
            $thumb_w=$old_x*($new_w/$old_y);
            $thumb_h=$new_h;
        }
        if ($old_x == $old_y){
            $thumb_w=$new_w;
            $thumb_h=$new_h;
        }
        $dst_img=ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y); 
        if (preg_match("/png/",$system[1])){
            imagepng($dst_img,$filename); 
        } else {
            imagejpeg($dst_img,$filename); 
        }

        imagedestroy($dst_img); 
        if(!imagedestroy($src_img)){
            $return = @unlink($filename);
            $return2 = @unlink($name);
            // Return FALSE if not found
            var_dump($return);
            var_dump($return2);
?>
            <script>alert("Unable to resize photos. Please check file/folder permission in admin/photos.");window.location ="index.php";</script>
<?php
        }

    }
    createthumb("uploads/" . $new_name,"uploads/thumbs/tn_" . $new_name,350,350);
    createthumb("uploads/" . $new_name,"uploads/small_thumbs/tn_" . $new_name,150,150);

    function ditchtn($arr,$thumbname){
        foreach ($arr as $item) {
            if (!preg_match("/^".$thumbname."/",$item)){$tmparr[]=$item;}
        }
        return $tmparr;
    }

    function directory($dir,$filters){
        $handle=opendir($dir);
        $files=array();
        if ($filters == "all"){while(($file = readdir($handle))!==false){$files[] = $file;}}
        if ($filters != "all"){
            $filters=explode(",",$filters);
            while (($file = readdir($handle))!==false){
                for ($f=0;$f<sizeof($filters);$f++):
                    $system=explode(".",$file);
                    if ($system[1] == $filters[$f]){$files[] = $file;}
                endfor;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        return $files;
    }
}
?>
```

**This is UpLoadFileclass.php**

```
<?php 
function  RandomFile($pass_len=12) {                   
            $allchar = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ; 
            $str = "" ; 
            mt_srand (( double) microtime() * 1000000 ); 
              for ($i=0; $i<$pass_len; $i++) 
                  $str .= substr( $allchar, mt_rand (0,25), 1 ) ; 
                  return $str ;
                  }    

      class UploadImage {         
                   var $image; 
                   var $imagesize; 
                   var $max_file_size; 
                   var $max_file_height; 
                   var $max_file_width; 
                   var $allowed; 
                   var $rename_file; 
                   var $path; 

       function UploadImage($image, $max_file_size, $max_file_height, $max_file_width, $field_name, $path, $rename_file=true) {                     
             $this->image=$image; 
             $this->max_file_size=$max_file_size; 
             $this->max_file_height=$max_file_height; 
             $this->max_file_width=$max_file_width; 
             $this->allowed = array( ".jpg"=>"2", ".jpeg"=>"2"); 
             $this->field_name = $field_name; 
             $this->path = $path; 
             $this->rename_file = $rename_file; 
        } 

        function ValidateUpload() {            
             if ($this->max_file_size <  filesize($this->image)) {                   
                  print("<span style=\"color:red;\">ERROR: Your File: ".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"]." is ".filesize($this->image)." KB, The max file size allowed is ".$this->max_file_size."</span>"); 
                    return false;                  
             }              
                $this->imagesize=getimagesize($this->image); 

                if ($this->max_file_width < $this->imagesize[0]) { 
                    print("<span style=\"color:red;\">ERROR:<br />Your File: ".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"]." is ".$this->imagesize[0]." pixels wide, the max file width allowed is ".$this->max_file_width."</span>");                     
                    return false;                        
                } 

                 if ($this->max_file_height < $this->imagesize[1]) {                        
                     print("<span style=\"color:red;\">ERROR:<br />Your File: ".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"]." is ".$this->imagesize[1]." pixels high, the max file height allowed is ".$this->max_file_height."<span>");                      
                      return false;                        
                }               
                return true; 
        } 

        function PrintForm($max_file_size) {           
              global $PHP_SELF;     
              print("<form action=\"$PHP_SELF\" method=\"POST\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\"></br>\n"); 
              print("<input type=file name=$this->field_name><br>\n");     
              print("<input type=hidden name=max_file_size value=".$max_file_size."><br>\n"); 
              print("<input type=submit name=submit><br>\n"); 
              print("</form>");                       
            }

        function CopyFile() {
            if($this->rename_file) {
            global $name, $ext;     

      switch($_FILES[$this->field_name]["type"]) { 

       case 'image/gif'; 
       $ext="gif"; 
       break; 

        case 'image/jpeg'; 
       $ext="jpg"; 
       break; 

        case 'image/pjpeg'; 
       $ext="jpg"; 
       break; 

        case 'image/png'; 
       $ext="png"; 
       break; 

        case 'application/x-shockwave-flash'; 
       $ext="swf"; 
       break; 

       case 'image/psd'; 
       $ext="psd"; 
       break; 

       case 'image/bmp'; 
       $ext="bmp"; 
       break; 
     } 

     $name=RandomFile();

         if(!copy($_FILES[$this->field_name]["tmp_name"],$this->path."/".$name.".".$ext)){
               print("<strong>There has been an error while uploading Filename:".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"] ."</strong>");                  
           } else {                
               print("Filename: ".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"] ." has been uploaded"); 
               //return  new file name
               return $name.".".$ext;                
           } 
           } else { 
           if(!file_exists($this->path."/".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"])) {                
                     if(!copy($_FILES[$this->field_name]["tmp_name"],$this->path."/". $_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"])) {
                        print("There has been an error uploading".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"]."please try again");                  
                        } else {
                            print("Filename:".$_FILES[$this->field_name]["name"]." has been uploaded");                
                   } 
                   } else { 
                   print("ERROR: A file by this name already exists"); 
                  } 
                 } 
                } 
               } 

?>
```

Once again, If anyone could help me to make sense of all of this, I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all again (in advance)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the includes to the page your form is on?

```
include_once("upload.php");
include_once("UpLoadFileclass.php");
```

Comment: then you can reference them in your form.

Comment: Hi Michael, I appreciate your help but this is WAYYYYYY More involved  than using include('FilesIWanttoInclude');

Comment: Michael, there are functions which need called etc (all sorts of stuff I can't get my head around). I don't think this can be solved by merely including the files as like I said, there are functions which need to be called "Activated" and more all of which I don't understand well enough to make good use of it so I'm hoping someone can spell it out for me.

Comment: I'm still fairly new at this myself but from what i have discovered so far is that functions you want to use repeatedly can be stored by themselves and then included into pages and called upon as needed. sorry i cannot be of more help like you I'm getting my head around it all still.